# On entropy in a de Sitter horizon in a universe undergoing accelerated expansion?

Tags: thermodynamics, cosmology, entropy, event-horizon, hawking-radiation

I have a question about de Sitter cosmological horizons:

In this video by Leonard Susskind (https://youtu.be/n7eW-xPEvoQ?t=2324) he explains the concept of the Poincaré recurrence using particles and the cosmological horizon. However I always thought that matter "falling" into the horizon was forever lost (like the galaxies we see receding and fading) and that it couldn't "return", so I'm not sure if I understood Susskind. Also, would this also happen in a universe without matter? I mean, I understand that cosmological horizons in a universe with a cosmological constant would radiate similarly to how a black hole would radiate Hawking radiations from its horizon. So shouldn't something similar to what Susskind explains happen but with radiated photons from the horizon?

Comment: These questions are rather loosely related, so better split them into separate posts (and include relevant links in each).